# Animation when scrolling with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, scroll, show-hide, flutter-animation

how can I make this animation on flutter? Anyone know of a widget that could help me?
[image of animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM6fK.gif)

Comment: check `SliverPersistentHeader`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CustomScrollView for such functionality.

Example:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    const SliverAppBar(
      pinned: true,
      expandedHeight: 250.0,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
    ),
    SliverGrid(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        childAspectRatio: 4.0,
      ),
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.teal[100 * (index % 9)],
            child: Text('Grid Item $index'),
          );
        },
        childCount: 20,
      ),
    ),
    SliverFixedExtentList(
      itemExtent: 50.0,
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
            child: Text('List Item $index'),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```